# i.landsat.toar in GRASS 7.8.2 "Unable to open header file"

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, landsat-8

I'm working with QGIS 3.12.1 and I'm using the GRASS tool `i.landsat.toar` with Landsat 8 images to convert DN to reflectance. Unfortunately, at every attempt I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Jacopo e Teo\Documents>i.landsat.toar sensor="oli8" method="dos4" date="2020-03-15" sun_elevation=38.75187762 product_date="2020-03-25" percent=0.01 pixel=1000 rayleigh=0 scale=1 -r -n input="rast_5e81b136e658e4." output=outpute55b5f6723a04dcdb2fa9b27a977d660 --overwrite
Calculating dark pixel of <rast_5e81b136e658e4.1>...
Calculating dark pixel of <rast_5e81b136e658e4.2>...
Calculating dark pixel of <rast_5e81b136e658e4.3>...
Calculating dark pixel of <rast_5e81b136e658e4.4>...
Calculating dark pixel of <rast_5e81b136e658e4.5>...
ERROR: Unable to open header file for raster <rast_5e81b136e658e4.6@
```

I already tried to rename the bands file in different ways, such:

- Just B1 for Band 1
- B, so using just the base name as pointed out by the manual https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/i.landsat.toar.html
- Band name without underscore, i.e. LC08L1TP192028202003152020032501T1B1

In every case, I obtain that same error. I'm working on the integrated QGIS interface, so not by console.

What could be a possible solution?

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE, I'll suggest you to have a look at following tutorial to better import and process Landsat data using GRASS tool. https://courses.neteler.org/processing-landsat8-data-in-grass-gis-7/

Comment: Please post the complete error message by editing your question ("ERROR: Unable to open header file for raster <rast_5e81b136e658e4.6@" seems to be cut)...